# How can i traduce this little C program in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

if i do this code all work fine:

```
word = "Hello World";;

number = 9 ;;

let main() =

    print_string word ;;
    print_int number ;;

main() ;;
```

Problem: I have to do a game for my university in OCaml, it must be modulariced, i made some functions but now i dont know how  can i call them at the same time, o how can i make an other function to call all of them, and that the last function return void.
The next code is what i am trying to do but i cant:
- i have a module Main.ml that imports a module Player.ml,
 in Player.ml i have the next code that dont work:

```
let print word number = ()

        let fun() =
            print_int number ;;
            print_string word ;;
```

then in `Main.ml` i have:

```
let main() =

      print "points player peter " 5 ;;

      print "points player mark" 7 ;;

main();;
```

So i am trying to do something imperative in ocaml and i dont know how..
In C i would do something like this:

in  `Player.c`

```
  void print(char *word, int number){

     fprintf(stdout,"%s", word);
     fprintf(stdout,"%d", number);
  }
```

in `Main.c`

```
int main(void){

print("point player peter ", 5);

print("points player mark", 8);

return 0;

}
```

My ocaml code is more complex, i have records, recursive functions, ect.. so i really need to traduce the previous C program to an Ocaml program.. I
think i am in problemss.. if you can help me thanks : )

Comment: What the heck is `traduce`?

Comment: Frenglish of "translate" came from traduire.

Comment: @Igna94, please learn how to format code in StackOverflow. Downvoted.

Comment: Yes, i must.. I am new and i was with few time. How do you do to make a block of code ? and in a comment how do you code ? i read the hide help buy i didnt understand ! @camispotter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your OCaml code, but I think the biggest issue is that your function `print` makes very little sense as a bit of OCaml code.

To get started, you should probably be defining `print` more like this:

```
 let print word number =
    print_string word;
    print_int number
```

Now you can call this function from other modules like this:

```
Player.print "peter" 18
```

I would also recommend that you reduce the use of `;;` in your code. Contrary to what is apparently the popular conception, `;;` is not required after every line of OCaml code. In my own source files there are no appearances of `;;` at all.

Most of your uses of `;;` should instead be `;`.

In a nutshell: `;;` is used to tell the toplevel (the REPL) to evaluate what you've typed so far. `;` is used to join two expressions into a single expression—by ignoring the value of the first expression. This really makes sense only in an imperative context, where the first expression has type `unit`.

If you'll forgive my speaking frankly, it would probably be a lot more productive to work through an OCaml tutorial than to ask for help here on StackOverflow before you have some basic mastery.